# Python ZipFile return extracted file path and name

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I have this current code to unzip the contents of `archive` to `extract_dir`. However, I cannot figure out how to get the extracted file path & name of the extracted file.

```
if archive.endswith((".zip")):
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(archive, 'r')
    zip_ref.extract(extract_dir)
    zip_ref.close()
```

For example, if the archive is called `test.zip` and ZipFile extracts the contents `test.exe` I want get `C:/windows/users/admin/downloads/test.exe` in to a variable?

EDIT: Sorry I wasn't clear, in the source code for [zipfile](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/zipfile.py#l1089) targetpath is returned I am wondering how I can get this?

Comment: What if there are multiple files in the zip?

Comment: That's not a zipfile issue. If you extracted files to a specific location (and you obviously know the location), and you want to get the files from there, you'll have to e.g. `os.walk` in that dir to get all files into a data structure.

Comment: If you don't supply a `path` arg to `ZipFile.extract` the archive members are extracted to the current working dir. You can get the list of archive members by name with [`zip_ref.namelist()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem then I would use extractall but that isn't a problem right now.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'll try using that i was just trying to do it a bit cleaner by using the `targetpath` the is is returned to the extract function in zipfile

Comment: The 1st arg to `ZipFile.extract` must be the member you want to extract, either in the form of a string, or a `ZipInfo` object. The path to extract can be given after the member arg.

Answer (score 13):

Here is the solution, I can't accept the answer for 2 days though.

```
if archive.endswith((".zip")):
    print "example.jpg"
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(archive, 'r')
    extracted = zip_ref.namelist()
    zip_ref.extractall(extract_dir)
    zip_ref.close()
    extracted_file = os.path.join(extract_dir, extracted[0])
```